# Running VLC video in pygame video always send error message in the end

Tags: python, video, media-player, vlc, playback

I was able to run a video in the pygame display via the VLC module, however in the end when closing the pygame window I always receive an error message

> [0000018278c0e800] mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
> [000001827990a070] mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
> [0000018279ab6c50] avcodec decoder: Using D3D11VA (Intel(R) UHD Graphics, vendor 8086(Intel), device 9b21, revision 2) for hardware decoding

Here is a sample script that causes the error:

```
import os
import sys
import vlc
import pygame

def callback():
    pass
def Play():

    # Get path to movie specified as command line argument
    movie = "Videos/Outro Placeholder.mpg"
    # Check if movie is accessible
    if not os.access(movie, os.R_OK):
        print('Error: %s file not readable' % movie)
        sys.exit(1)

    # Create instane of VLC and create reference to movie.
    vlcInstance = vlc.Instance()
    media = vlcInstance.media_new(movie)

    # Create new instance of vlc player
    player = vlcInstance.media_player_new()

    # Add a callback
    em = player.event_manager()
    em.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerTimeChanged, \
        callback, player)

    # Pass pygame window id to vlc player, so it can render its contents there.
    win_id = pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window']
    if sys.platform == "linux2": # for Linux using the X Server
        player.set_xwindow(win_id)
    elif sys.platform == "win32": # for Windows
        player.set_hwnd(win_id)
    elif sys.platform == "darwin": # for MacOS
        player.set_agl(win_id)

    # Load movie into vlc player instance
    player.set_media(media)

    # Quit pygame mixer to allow vlc full access to audio device (REINIT AFTER MOVIE PLAYBACK IS FINISHED!)
    pygame.mixer.quit()

    # Start movie playback
    player.play()

    while player.get_state() != vlc.State.Ended:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit(2)
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
Play()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

I really could not find any solution to it.
Why could this be happening?

Comment: maybe you have to `.close()` player before `exit()` ?

Comment: unfortunately no, I already tried that.

On version of test script would look like this for example:

`while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            vlc.MediaPlayer().stop()
            player.stop()
            player.release()
            sys.exit()`

but it still creates the same error.
Oddly enough I find basically nothing about those error messages on the internet.